# Display Polygons Layers according to zoom level of the map and clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, geojson

So I have an OpenStreetMap map(with Leaflet), and I put a Europe javascript layer (I inserted Id in the javascript to differentiate every countries). Each country highlight when I do a hover on it with my mouse. When I click on a country, it automatically zoom on it.

And I would like, that, when I click on the country, the layer of the country disappear (according to the zoom level) (but the other countries have to stay "layered". (knowing that, after that, I will try to put markers on a country that will display only if the country layer disappears, and where we can zoom on it by clicking on it).

Ps: I followed this website to do what I have at this moment :
    https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

And the my code :
https://jsfiddle.net/Gio687351/3bwsnu8z/2/

```
map.on('zoomend ', function(e) {
    if (map.getZoom() < 3) {
        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds())
        map.removeLayer(Europe-Layer.js)
        map.setStyle({
            'fillOpacity': '0.7'
        });
    } else if (map.getZoom() >= 3) {
        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds())
        map.addLayer(statesData);
        map.setStyle({
            'fillOpacity': '0.0'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layer visibility could be managed via `fill-opacity` and `opacity` [style properties](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Geojson_CSS) as demonstrated below:

```
function toggleLayerVisibility(map, layer) {
  if (selectedLayerId) {
    geojson.resetStyle(layer);
    selectedLayerId = null;
  } else {
    //hide a layer
    layer.setStyle({
      opacity: 0,
      fillOpacity: 0.0
    });
    selectedLayerId = layer._leaflet_id; //save identifier of a selected layer
  }
}
```

Explanation:

- setting `opacity: 0` and `fillOpacity: 0` hides the layer
- `selectedLayerId` is used to store the identifier of currently selected layer

Given the provided example, the [following demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1iTy4HbghAkTpbXdfnBv?p=preview) demonstrates how to hide a clicked layer

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much ! I am so grateful !